# Removing oldest file in directory with spaces in name

Tags: linux, unix, rm

Hi everyone I'm trying to remove a file in a directory that has spaces in the name I'm currently trying to do this

```
rm `ls -t1 | tail -1`
```

only problem I have is that I can't remove the oldest file if it has spaces in the name

Is there a work around this?

Thanks!

Comment: This question might be get better answers on [unix.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rm "$(ls -t|tail -1)"
```

(The `1` argument to `ls` isn't needed.)

Comment: Hi thanks! I have a followup question to that what if I wanted to remove the oldest file in a subdirectory?  I tried rm "$(ls -t subdirectory | tail -1)" but it says no such file even though it shows it?

Comment: Change the `rm` to `echo` and you'll see that the path isn't included -- you're trying to remove it from the current directory. You could `cd` to the subdirectory first.

Comment: that's weird cause when i use echo it still shows the file i just can't rm it from the parent directory?  does it have something to do with the spaces in the file name?

Comment: here's what terminal is giving me: rm: cannot remove 'file Sun Jun 29' : no such file or directory

Comment: Is that a filename or part of a date? My point was, say the subdir is `sub` and the file is `somefile`. The `ls` is giving you `somefile` but you need to `rm sub/somefile`. The path isn't included.